# Facebook OpenGraph Protocol?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I installed the official facebook wordpress plugin, it helps to automatically add the following lines of code to my page:

```
<meta property="http://ogp.me/ns#locale" content="en_US" />
<meta property="http://ogp.me/ns#site_name" content="XXX" />
<meta property="http://ogp.me/ns#type" content="article" />
<meta property="http://ogp.me/ns#title" content="Contact" />
<meta property="http://ogp.me/ns#url" content="http://XXX.com" />
<meta property="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#app_id" content="XXX" />
```

Now I want to add a LIKE BOX to my page,

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

When I choose 'XFBML' code, it showed:

"Add an XML namespace to the  tag of your document. This is necessary for XFBML to work in earlier versions of Internet Explorer."

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

My question is that do I still need to add this one line of code considering I already got the "meta property" added above? If I add this, would it conflict with "meta property"??

Also which versions of IE need that line of code?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">`
>
> My question is that do I still need to add this one line of code considering I already got the "meta property" added above?

You *would* still need that, because it has nothing to do with Open Graph meta elements (which just provide some info about the document for “outside” parties like Facebook’s scraper), but with how the browser treats “unknown” tags in your document (and `<fb:like-box>` is such an unknown tag, because it does not exist in HTML).

> If I add this, would it conflict with "meta property"??

No, there is no potential for any sort of “conflict” here.

> Also which versions of IE need that line of code?

I don’t know exactly, but I’d guess at least 6 & 7.

If for some reason (CMS, whatever) you *can not* add this to the HTML element – then you can just use the *HTML5* version of the plugin code instead – that uses just a normal `DIV` element, and that is not “unknown” to any browser. (Your document’s doctype does not have to be the HTML5 one for this to work.)

Comment: Thanks, actually there are four options, I picked XFBML since I read that it is more powerful or something, is it true? Do you know which option is preferred by Facebook?  I just hope to pick one that wouldn't be deprecated soon :-)

Comment: The HTML5 version is actually what FB themselves call _“the HTML5 compatible version of using XFBML”_, so they are basically pretty much the same. Which version you prefer (one of those, or the iframe/URL one), is up to you.